# Can kinetic energy be converted to mass directly without getting converted into other forms of energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy-conservation, mass-energy

Are kinetic energy and potential energy both directly convertible to mass?

Comment: Any particular type of potential energy in mind, or for all fundamental forces?

Comment: For gravitational and elastic potential energy

Answer (score 1):

For Kinetic energy: yes.

In nuclear decay the total mass of the decay products is less than the original nuclear mass by the kinetic energy of the radiation.

The reaction is reversible, although less easy to achieve.

For potential energy: no.

Potential energy alters when the position of a particle changes. A change in position requires some kinetic energy. 
Consequently kinetic energy will be present as an intermediary.

Answer (score 1):

If by "convert" you mean the production of new particles, then I agree with @JMLCarter answer wholeheartedly. But if you accept to consider whether potential energy may contribute to the inertial and gravitational mass of a body, there is something to say.

As you may have heard, when it comes to gravitation, there are a priori two different masses for a body. I am talking about a macroscopic body here, from a ball of metal to a planet let's say. There is the inertial mass, that says how quickly it accelerates when a force is applied to it (the more inertial mass, the slower, in a linear relation). And there is the gravitational mass, which says how strongly it will feel the gravity of other bodies (the more gravitational mass, the bigger the force it feels, in a linear relation). An essential tenet of modern physics  is that

- both masses are exactly the same (which allows to speak only of "the mass");
- both masses get contributions for any form of energy all the way down to microscopic levels.

So for example the inertial mass of a small ball of metal will get a contribution of about 1% from the nuclear binding energies that keep the protons and the neutrons of its nuclei together: a form of potential energy, I would argue. Experimental tests of this compare the inertial and the gravitational mass: a priori there is no reason that each type of energy would contribute the same amount to both masses. But it is very well confirmed that it does.

Finally, the kinetic energy of the constituents of those balls of metal does also equally contributes to both inertial and gravitational masses. An estimation for the kinetic energy of electrons can be found in [1]. This paper contains references for the binding energies too actually, including one I did not mention: the gravitational self-energy of the Earth contributes to its mass.

[1] Steven Carlip. Kinetic energy and the equivalence principle. Am. J. Phys., 66:409–413, 1998.

Answer (score 0):

It is all semantics. Sure you can slam particles together at high speeds and do what you're saying, but you could also say that mass and energy are already the same. It is not a very interesting question. There is no single answer.